# Tableau - Basic Graph

Tags: tableau-api

I've created a simple line graph in tableau. I'd like to add a drop down box where I can select from to change the line graph's X axis? How do I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a parameter str datatype and put dimension name you want to change.

then create a calculated field named x-axis
and use a

```
case parameter 
when 'dim1' then dim1
.
.
end
```

put this calculate field on x-axis